# What's the correct way to programmatically disable a ngx-select-ex selector?

Tags: angular

I get the following error when trying to disable a ngx-select-ex selector: "
It looks like you're using the disabled attribute with a reactive form directive". I understand what the error message is saying, but is there anyway to programmatically disable the control using a variable, like:

```
<ngx-select id="ngxControl" [formControl]="ngxControl"
                [allowClear]="true"                    
                [items]="items"
                [disabled]="disabledTypeSelectors"
                placeholder="No city selected">
</ngx-select>


enableDisable() {
  this.disabledTypeSelectors = !this.disabledTypeSelectors;
}
```

I've got an example here: `https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s4bkg5`
The html is at: app/hero-detail/hero-detail.component.html (scroll to the bottom of that code to see it).[image: see error message]

Comment: You have to call `ngxControl.disable()` or `ngxControl.enable()`. This isn't a ngx issue. You're using Angular's reactive forms which doesn't support the disabled attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [disable](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#disable) and [enable](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#enable) [AbstractControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl) methods.

Modified example: https://angular-s4bkg5-mb72pq.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 0):

Disable using the form controller.

for ex: `<formGroup>.controls['ngxControl'].disable()`